# Why is MySQL's default collation latin1_swedish_ci?

Tags: mysql, collation

What is the reasoning behind setting `latin1_swedish_ci` as the compiled default when other options seem much more reasonable, like `latin1_general_ci` or `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does MySQL use latin1\_swedish\_ci as the default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936059/why-does-mysql-use-latin1-swedish-ci-as-the-default)

Comment: Please note that `utf8_general_ci` does not support 4-byte UTF-8 so for true UTF-8 support you would want `utf8mb4_general_ci` or one of the other `mb4` variants.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

[The bloke who wrote it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Widenius) was co-head of a [Swedish company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_AB).

Possibly for similar reasons, Microsoft SQL Server's default language us_english.

Comment: He is Finnish , but Finnish and Swedish share almost the same special characters ,so they share the same case insensitive collation

Comment: Talking about 'good defaults'. Which this, of course, is not. Great to see that after what, 20 years? they changed this into a sane default, like ```utf8_general_ci```. Good job, MySQL !

Comment: Yes you are right, He named MariDB (Wife name is Maria) and MaxDB (His son name is Max). but why he left his Daughter name..! :)
LOL. !

Comment: @AjmalPraveen Monty named his database projects in chronological order after his kids; My, Max and Maria.

Comment: @VexingParse Oh, I see..

Comment: @MichaelTrouw the latin1 charset can be a good default as it is far smaller than utf8. So if your field is a username which can only be a-z and 0-9, I see no reason why all sorts of characters (to name a few: emoji, Ethiopic syllables, and many more) should be acceptable at the cost of resources.

Comment: well, yes, but don't design your DB around the requirements for just a username :)

Answer (score 109):

`latin1_swedish_ci` is a single byte character set, unlike `utf8_general_ci`.

Compared to `latin1_general_ci` it has support for a variety of extra characters used in European languages. So it’s a best choice if you don’t know what language you will be using, if you are constrained to use only single byte character sets.

Comment: I like this answer because it tries to objectively justify the choice of latin swedish.  However, the accepted answer seems a more plausible explanation, from a social perspective, for why swedish was chosen in particular.

Comment: It's certainly possible that this was the author's reasoning, and just a coincidence that he's Swedish.  It seems reasonable that a Swede would want (and know) to support additional European characters.

Comment: -1 The accepted answer could be just an opinion but it is 100 times more reasonable than this answer. Also , you can see that "the bloke who wrote it" also named MariaDB after his daugther and maxDB after his son.

Comment: "latin1_general_ci it has support for a variety of extra characters used in European languages" - Just to make this clear, utf8_general_ci, unlike utf8_unicode, does have a wide support for European languages specific chars. I don't see an advantage over "latin1_swedish_ci". Or am I wrong?

Comment: For example, CHAR(2) latin1 uses 2 bytes, CHAR(2) utf8mb4 (which is full utf8) uses 8 bytes. I use latin1 to store 2-digit country codes because there will never be non-european characters